# What's the best way to keep database versioning with the yii php framework?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, database, yii

Coming from the ruby on rails world, I'm looking for an efficient way to version my database (in case of rails, migration serves that purpose).

Currently I'm taking snapshots of the database and exporting the entire schema on a regular bases, but the entire process is pretty manual.

Is there a better way to do this?

p.s. I'm using mysql.

Comment: I don't know anything about PHP and what is available in that world. But you can always use liquibase, which enables database versioning, rollbacks, etc, in a platform agnostic way (it's written in Java).

Comment: I'd like to here more about what you're trying to accomplish. Are you just updating other database(s) with the schema of one master db? If so, how many? The MySQL db service definitely provides mechanisms for slave servers, which are subscribed to all changes and will then replicate all actions on the master. You wouldn't need PHP to implement that.

Comment: zanlok,  I'm not trying to deploy slave servers.  There are many benefits that come with a db versioning system.  For example, it's easier to coordinate between developers / code branches and keep references to database schema changes.  Any type of manual process is prone to human error.  In this day and age I figured there should be many systems that automatically track your changes and date them.

Comment: Database versioning module for Kohana - http://blog.kicaj.com/database-schema-versioning-in-php/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Yii 1.1.6 there will be concept of *database migrations*. This will allow us to do database manipulation in DB-agnostic way using PHP code. See http://code.google.com/p/yii/issues/detail?id=1191 for more details.

Comment: +1 For the cool tip. We currently use our own tool based on dbdeploy (the implementation at the time we needed it was really **** so we wrote our own). This works really well for us. Although will definitely checkout the Yii implementation as soon as 1.1.6 comes out officially :)

Comment: I was thinking of using migrations functionality provided by Doctrine project. However "out of the box" solution is always nice

Answer (score 0):

Basically: **NO**. Not something stock with php.

*HOWEVER*... Reconciling scheme, such as from a `SHOW CREATE <table_name>;` command, is still a reliable way to do what you're talking about -- if quite nontrivial in nature. You have to be very aware of the particulars in mechanics of schema definition if you're to detect and replicate that. You are free to develop a specialized field, though, that tracks a version number which you update when updating the schema. Then, at least you'd know when the other replication targets need to be updated as well -- by comparing the data in that version field.

The way I've usually seen this implemented is to track all ALTER TABLE commands (etc) and track them. You could check in something like an 'r12345.sql' file into SVN for a system of automatically executing db updates. It's involved, but what I mean is that a php script can check against all the db schema .sql files and execute each of the ones (in series) that will play back the changes onto the current database.

A lot depends on what you're trying to accomplish. If you provide more info, I'd expound.